# Making a recommendation to a recruiter

Tags: canada

I recently got a new position through a recruiting agency. My understanding of the process is that the recruiter makes a commission based on my employment for bringing me into this position.

My question regards a friend of mine who is also currently looking for work (same field, same background, etc). They are still hiring for multiple positions, and I am certain he would easily qualify.

Would it be considered unwanted for me to actively seek a reward for bringing forward a candidate?

A few things I should probably note...

- This is not a closed application environment, it is open to the public.
- I could not find any information on the website either of my employer or recruiter regarding this situation.

Comment: Reach out to HR and inquire about a referral policy. Usually if your referred candidate is selected and joins, you get a token amount of appreciation. However, this is entirely at discretion of the organization and it varies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes the company you work will give you a bonus if a person you recommend  is hired and works there for a period of time.  You need to contact HR or your manager for details.  I have found that HR periodically contacts all employees about the program as a reminder, and also does this when they are making a special push for resumes; you are so new you may not have received a notice yet.

There are usually conditions on the program, you can't be part of the hiring decision, and their resume can't already be in the system.

The company would rather pay a current employee some money as apposed to paying an external recruiter. Some external reciters do have similar incentives, but it would look strange to your new employer if they found out that you got money from the recruiter. It is possible that the contract between your employer and the recruiter would forbid this.

I would start with HR. I have seen even very small companies have a bonus program.

Comment: So it looks like - speak with HR, but don't talk to the recruiter about it. That seems solid, I never thought what my employer would think if they found out somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on your company policy. Many companies offer referral bonuses for employees who refer a new hire. You would be best to ask your boss or someone in your company's HR if they have a policy that would apply to you.

The finder's fee for an external recruiter is completely separate and would have no impact on if you were to get a referral bonus. I would not bring this up with them at all.